Data factory Cosmso Data Copy to other cosmos
I am using Cosmos as Source to copy in other cosmos account using data flow but it changing time stamp (_ts).
Tried checking (include system column)

Can you provide your dataflow transformations? sample data and expected results and any errors or blockers that you got?

_ts is the internal system generated property of each document which indicates the timestamp at which that document was created or modified. You can view the system property od source container by checking `system column` check box in source option. But you cannot copy this value to the sink container. In sink, _ts value of each document will be the timestamp at which the data is copied.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/resource-model#properties-of-an-item
